# Why analysing multiple URL addresses with Wappalyzer causes 'heap out of memory' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to analyse about 1000 websites with Wappalyzer to find out if they are using Magento. The results of analysis is ok, but after 10-11 tests appears 'heap out of memory' error. How can I avoid it?

```
function analyseUrl(url) {
    const options = {
        debug: false,
        delay: 500,
        maxDepth: 5,
        maxUrls: 20,
        maxWait: 15000,
        recursive: true,
        htmlMaxCols: 2000,
        htmlMaxRows: 2000,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new Wappalyzer(url, options).analyze()
            .then( json => {
                for (let i = 0; i < json.applications.length; i++) {
                    if (json.applications[i].name === "Magento") {
                        console.log('Magento URL: ' + url);
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                }
                resolve(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}

async function wappalyze() {
    urls = getUrls();
    let magentoUrls = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        console.log('Testing URL: ' + urls[i]);
        let isMagento = await analyseUrl(urls[i]);
        if (isMagento) {
            magentoUrls.push(urls[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(magentoUrls);
    process.exit(0);
}
```

My script is giving expected results, but after tenth test I got MaxListenersExceededWarning and after that: "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".

Comment: Increase the heap size? Sounds like Wappalyzer is leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Each wappalyzer instance is actually creating a headless browser in the background so you were running 10 Chromium instances and went oom. The solution lies inside the source code

```
analyze() {
this.time = {
  start: new Date().getTime(),
  last: new Date().getTime(),
};

return this.crawl(this.origPageUrl);
```

}

You just need to initiate one instance of wappalyzer then call url.parse to parse the url string first, and then pass this object to your wappalyzer object crawl method (1 instance). I haven't tried with multiple instances though.